# Unknown package in Tclsh shell

Tags: tcl

When I am running my Tcl script, it is saying "`can't find package sqlite3`" while executing.

So what should I do ?

**Edit:** It looks I don't have the sqlite3 package installed in my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the sqlite3 package is not in a location where the Tcl interpreter can find it. Is the package even installed on that machine? If not, that's your problem right there.

Otherwise, if the library is present then the problem is that the Tcl interpreter hasn't been told where to look. There's a few reasons why this might be so, but you can generally fix this without editing your script by setting the `TCLLIBPATH` environment variable before running Tcl. For example, on my system (macOS, but the principles are cross-platform), the sqlite installation is in `/Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib/sqlite33.8.10.2/` (specifically, there's a `pkgIndex.tcl` and `libsqlite3.8.10.2.dylib` there; the latter name is a platform-specific detail though) so I would run tclsh with:

```
export TCLLIBPATH=/Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib
tclsh myScript.tcl
```

**I do not expect the paths to be the same for you!** The key thing here is that you can find where things are installed and set `TCLLIBPATH` to make things work.

---

You can also put:

```
lappend ::auto_path /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib
```

inside your script *before* the first `package require`, but that binds the script to a particular system installation layout so we don't recommend it for anything other than a local hack.

Comment: I know it is not appropriate to say. But, may i get your email address ? Because I want to run a Tcl script over the last few months but yet not successful. The reason is i want to send the script to you for help because i can't share in this forum as a question. It is some confidential